how can I use DBMS_CRYPTO instead of DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT because its no longer supported?
I am using this function HASH_PASSWORD
when I executed this function to MAXAPEX cloud I cannot execute this function because they using 21c database and this function no longer supported how to change the function and use DBMS_CRYPTO instead of  DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT   ?
create or replace FUNCTION HASH_PASSWORD 
 
  (p_user_name in varchar2, 
 
   p_password  in varchar2) 
 
return varchar2 
 
is 
 
  l_password varchar2(255); 
 
  -- The following salt is an example.  
 
  -- Should probably be changed to another random string. 
 
  l_salt  varchar2(255) := '2345USFGOJN2T3HW89EFGOBN23R5SDFGAKL'; 
   L_ENCRP_PASSWORD VARCHAR2(8); 
 L_PASS_LENGTH    NUMBER(1); 
 L_PASS_ASCII     NUMBER(8); 
 
begin 
 
    -- 
 
    -- The following encryptes the password using a salt string and the  
 
    -- DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT.  
 
    -- This is a one-way encryption using MD5 
 
    --  
 
   l_password := utl_raw.cast_to_raw ( 
 
                    dbms_obfuscation_toolkit.md5( 
 
                      input_string => p_password || 
 
                                      substr(l_salt,4,14) || 
 
                                      p_user_name || 
 
                                      substr(l_salt,5,10))); 
                                      
 /* 
 L_PASS_LENGTH := LENGTH(P_PASSWORD); 
 
 
 FOR I IN 1..L_PASS_LENGTH LOOP 
     L_PASS_ASCII := L_PASS_ASCII + (ASCII(SUBSTR(P_PASSWORD,I,1)) * I ); 
 END LOOP; 
 
  l_password := L_PASS_ASCII + 15; 
 */ 
 
    return l_password; 
 
end hash_password; 
 
-- AUTHENTICATE USER Function; 
/


You can use STANDARD_HASH or DBMS_CRYPTO where both give the same results as per the below tested procedure
        - Should probably be changed to another random string. 
    declare
      l_salt           varchar2(255) := '2345USFGOJN2T3HW89EFGOBN23R5SDFGAKL';
      L_ENCRP_PASSWORD VARCHAR2(8);
      L_PASS_LENGTH    NUMBER(1);
      L_PASS_ASCII     NUMBER(8);
      l_password       varchar2(255);
    begin

      -- 

      -- The following encryptes the password using a salt string and the  

      -- DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT.  

      -- This is a one-way encryption using MD5 

      --  

      l_password := utl_raw.cast_to_raw(
                                        
                                        dbms_obfuscation_toolkit.md5(
                                                                     
                                                                     input_string => 'SAN' ||
                                                                                    
                                                                                     substr(l_salt,
                                                                                            4,
                                                                                            14) ||
                                                                                    
                                                                                     'BADSHA' ||
                                                                                    
                                                                                     substr(l_salt,
                                                                                            5,
                                                                                            10)));
      dbms_output.put_line(l_password);
      
      select rawtohex(DBMS_CRYPTO.Hash(UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW('SAN' ||
                                                              
                                                              substr(l_salt,
                                                                     4,
                                                                     14) ||
                                                              
                                                              'BADSHA' ||
                                                              
                                                              substr(l_salt,
                                                                     5,
                                                                     10),
                                                              'AL32UTF8'),
                                       2))
        into l_password
        from dual;

      dbms_output.put_line(l_password);

      select standard_hash('SAN' ||
                           
                           substr(l_salt, 4, 14) ||
                           
                           'BADSHA' ||
                           
                           substr(l_salt, 5, 10),
                           'MD5')
        into l_password
        from dual;

      dbms_output.put_line(l_password);

    end;


I created new function and its working
create or replace function HIS_HASH_PASSWORD
    (P_USERNAME in varchar2,
     P_PASSWORD in varchar2)
    return varchar2 is
    l_password varchar2(4000);
    l_hash_function number;
begin
   l_hash_function := dbms_crypto.hash_sh1;
   l_password := dbms_crypto.hash(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(P_USERNAME||P_PASSWORD),l_hash_function);
   return l_password;
end;
/

